# Loading Relations in Tree Entity : TypeORM

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have many doubts related to using Tree Entities in TypeORM,
this is my
`commment.entity.ts`

```js
@Entity()
@Tree('closure-table')
export class Comments extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({ nullable: false })
  commentBody: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.comments)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
  user: User;

  @ManyToOne(() => Posts, (post) => post.comments)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'post_id' })
  post: Posts;

  @TreeChildren()
  children: Comments[];

  @TreeParent()
  parent: Comments;

}
```

what I am trying to do here is that, user can create a comment on `Post`

so, user -> comment  (OneToMany relation)
and post -> comment  (OneToMany relation)

and my `post.entity.ts`

```js
@Entity('posts')
export class Posts extends FakeBaseEntity {
  @Column({ length: 200, nullable: true })
  caption: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'author_id' })
  author: User;

  @OneToMany(() => Comments, (comment) => comment.post)
  comments: Comments[];
}
```

When I am trying to get any `Post` I want all the comments (i.e with all the childrens) associated with them

my approach is somewhat like this,

```js
const posts = await this.postsRepo
      .createQueryBuilder('posts')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('posts.author', 'author')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('posts.comments', 'comments')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('comments.children', 'replies') // gets only one children of it
      .leftJoinAndSelect('comments.user', 'commentUser')
      .where('posts.author = :userid', { userid });
```

through this query I am able to get only, children even though if it has more than one children

So, how do I return all the comments associated with a single comment (i.e) with all the childrens of it ?

Answer (score -1):

```
const posts = await this.postsRepo
      .createQueryBuilder('posts')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('posts.author', 'author')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('posts.comments', 'comments')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('comments.children', 'replies') // gets only one children of it
      .leftJoinAndSelect('comments.user', 'commentUser')
      .where('posts.author = :userid', { userid })   .getRawMany();
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.